# Change pluses to spaces urlib unquote

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
 name = urllib.unquote(d[1]).decode('utf8')
```

I use this name taken from form with Post method, to send an Email;
As a result if name contains spaces they transdorm to pluses:
For example:

> Hello John+Smith

How to change pluses to space characters.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus That should be an answer. Not a comment! :-)

Comment: yes @ZeroPiraeus provide this as an answer please=)

Comment: @PankajParashar I disagree. The question should be a thirty second Google search, not a question. Refusing to answer and downvoting means trash like this will be automatically deleted.

Comment: I disagree with you, if I asked this  I found difficult to find an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

something like this will work:
name = urllib.unquote_plus(d[1]).decode('utf8')
as Zero Piraeus stated in comments